# Complete Regex Reference For Salesforce Formulas?

Tags: administration, workflow, formula, field-update, regular-expressions

Is there a *complete* **Regex Reference** somewhere for using REGEX() in formulas?

I have searched and found nothing useful.

---

The problem I am having is below.  I want to know if any of the characters listed are in a field.

```
.*(\\_\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\+\\=\\{\\[\\}\\]\\|\\:\\;\\?\\/\\<).*
```

Based on my limited knowledge of Regex, I would tend to believe I may be backslashing a character that DOES NOT NEED it.   I could by trial and error figure that out, but I'd rather also find a true reference to Regex beyond the tiny entry in SF's Help site.

**Another minor note**:  Anyone know why I can NOT have

```
\\\\
```

check for backslash within the first example?  In it's OWN check, four slashes seem to work fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best resource I know of for Regex is [GSkinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) which has a built in Regular Expression builder and test utility. The main thing to know is that SF doesn't support any of the flags that can be specified as used on that site and Java RegEx classes.

Comment: I had been hopefully when I wrote this that there was something specific to SF, but I'm accepting this answer as it really comes down to understanding BOTH RegEx and SF adequately enough.  Thanks.  ;)

Comment: Another reference that may be useful to you and a bit more definitive is the [Oracle Regex Pattern Matcher Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).